# Добавить поле типа File к заказу в MODX Revo (Minishop2)

Tags: файлы, modx, fileupload, minishop2, order

Необходимо добавить файл с вложением в оформление заказа на minishop 2.
Нужно, чтобы этот файл можно было посмотреть из админки в данных заказа.
Не нашел ни одной инструкции, как это реализовать.
Этот мануал подходит только для текстовых полей.
https://dart.agency/blog/modx/kak-dobavit-dopolnitelnoe-pole-k-zakazu-v-minishop2.html

Господа, знающие MODX, буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: Сам ищу такое решение. Вы в итоге как реализовали?
Пока вижу только платный компонент: https://modstore.pro/packages/integration/msorderfiles